# How can I map a generic abstraction to a generic implementation in Simple Injector?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, simple-injector, di-containers

I could not come of with a better title so please feel free to change it after you have read the entire question.

I have the following classes:

```
public class Foo<T> : IFoo<T> {}
public interface IFoo<T> { }
```

I would like to be able to inject `IFoo<T>` arguments in such a way:

```
public class MyService 
{
    public MyService(IFoo<SomeClass> whatever) {}
}
```

How can I configure the container without having to register every single registration? i.e. I want to avoid having to do this:

```
container.Register<IFoo<SomeClass>>(new Foo<SomeClass>());
container.Register<IFoo<SomeOtherClass>>(new Foo<SomeOtherClass>());
...
```

Instead I want to do something like this (pseudo code):

```
container.Register<IFoo<T>>(new Foo<T>());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
container.Register(typeof(IFoo<>), typeof(Foo<>));
```

Read more about it [here](https://simpleinjector.org/advanced#registration-of-open-generic-types).

Comment: What about the types that are outside the `IFoo<>` assembly? `IFoo<>` could live in a library that users reference and `SomeClass` could be in the user's assembly.

Comment: I updated this answer, because it used the batch-registration overload (accepting assemblies), while this ignores generic implementations, such as `Foo<T>`. Instead, by mapping the generic interface to the generic type, allows Simple Injector to inject a closed version of Foo when IFoo is requested.

Comment: @Steven Excellent! exactly what I was looking for, You just need to modify the second parameter to: `typeof(Foo<>)`.